# web apps on localhost on different ports accessed via port 80

Tags: web, port, mod-proxy

### On my laptop, with Apache

I have different web apps in various directories on my laptop, that I can start using simple webservers listening on different ports. For example

```
~/app1/./app.pl
>> listening on http://localhost:3000/

~/app2/./app.pl
>> listening on http://localhost:3001/

~/app3/./app.pl
>> listening on http://localhost:3001/
```

I want to access the above from my browser like so

```
http://localhost/app1
http://localhost/app2
http://localhost/app3
```

Can I do the above with mod_proxy? If so, how?

Update: I must add that I have Googled for mod_proxy, read the tutes on Apache's website, and experimented with the following

uncommented the following in my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

added the following in my httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPass /app3 http://localhost:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse /app3 http://localhost:3002/
</IfModule>
```

Yet, I get HTTP 404 when I try to access the above apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using mod_rewrite and mod_proxy. For example (the following rules
go into your VirtualHost configuration):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/app1(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^/app2(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^/app3(.*)$ http://localhost:3002/$1 [P]
```

These rules use mod_rewrite's `[P]` flag to proxy the request. You'll need to make
sure that mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and mod_rewrite are all loaded in your main apache configuration by adding/uncommenting:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: ok, let me get this straight... do I need to use mod_proxy *with* mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes, you'd need both mod_proxy and mod_rewrite enabled for this to work. You can do it with mod_proxy alone (and in a simple case like yours that might be better) but mod_rewrite gives you more flexibility when mapping URLs, so it's normally my first choice for this job.

Comment: ok. Could you please spell this step by step? If you see from my note above, I am unable to make this work with mod_proxy. What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing? I don't have to worry about mapping URLs because my web application does that by itself. I just want to point the browser to http://localhost/app1, but have Apache redirect it behind the scene to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: How does this deal with links that are internally generated by the app? e.g. If app1 has javascript pointing to /js when it fact it should be going to /app1/js, this won't work. How can it though without rewriting the apps source code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Googling "mod_proxy tutorial" has plenty of results...

In particular you'll want to use mod_proxy_ajp if your server supports the AJP protocol. (Such as Tomcat.)

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't even want to go near Tomcat.

Comment: @punkish: It was just an example and AJP is also used in Jetty. I did not say it was only Tomcat.